# How to select distinct items without having to use in group by clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find `sum` of some columns using SQL like this:

```
      select   distinct  c.customer,
       c.customer_id,
       sum(d.delay) as delay,
       sum(d.delayed_amount) as delay_amt,
       pd.product

  from product pd
  inner join mfg_company mfg on pd.product_id=mfg.product_id
  inner join store s on mfg.store_id = s.store_id
  inner join customer c on s.customer = c.customer_id
  join delay_detail d on pd.product_id = d.material
 where d.product_mfg_id = 466
 group by c.customer,customer_id
 order by c.customer,c.customer_id
```

The problem is `mfg_company` has duplicate product_id's(multiple mappings) ,So when I am trying to find the `sum` it's including those duplicates too.
Using `product_id` in group by clause doesn't help the result I want to see.So how to join only on distinct product_id's?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution to your problem is to pre-aggregate the delays.  It is entirely unclear if you want the product in the result set.  Assuming you do not:

```
select c.customer, c.customer_id,
       sum(d.delay) as delay, sum(d.delay_amt) as delay_amt
from product pd join
     mfg_company mfg
     on pd.product_id = mfg.product_id join
     store s
     on mfg.store_id = s.store_id
     customer c
     on s.customer = c.customer_id join
     (select d.material, sum(d.delay) as delay, sum(d.delayed_amount) as delay_amt
      from delay_detail d
      group by d.material
     ) d
     on pd.product_id = d.material
where d.product_mfg_id = 466
group by c.customer, customer_id
order by c.customer, c.customer_id;
```

Note that using `select distinct` with `group by` is almost never needed.

Comment: You assumed it right,but it's still throwing `not a group by expression` at d.delay

Comment: My issue is similar to grouping by ignoring one column,in this case 'd.material'

Comment: it doesn't group by customer and customer id.Shows multiple records for one single customer,i want all that under one group

Comment: @Sherlock.H . . . Those need to be aggregated.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: I have tried that already,still getting those duplicate values too

Comment: I guess that select statement in the join,instead of ignoring a second occurrence,it's just adding the sum to the old instance .maybe we should use something like `distinct` instead of `group by`

Answer (score 0):

You can try below query if this helps -

```
 select distinct c.customer
                ,c.customer_id
                ,sum(d.delay) as delay
                ,sum(d.delayed_amount) as delay_amt
                ,pd.product
 from product pd
 inner join (select distinct product_id
                            ,store_id
             from mfg_company) mfg on pd.product_id=mfg.product_id
 inner join store s on mfg.store_id = s.store_id
 inner join customer c on s.customer = c.customer_id
 join delay_detail d on pd.product_id = d.material
 where d.product_mfg_id = 466
 group by c.customer,customer_id
 order by c.customer,c.customer_id
```

Comment: tried this before posting here,still duplicates gets included